# Automatically restarting a Rails app and running Rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rake, rake-task

I have a Rails application that pulls information from various internal APIs and stores in a local SQLite DB. My rails application is essentially a glorified UI on top of this data pulled from multiple APIs.

For reasons outside the scope of this question, it is not straightforward to simply update the information in the DB on a periodic basis by re-querying the API. I'm basically forced to recreate the DB from scratch.

In essence I want to do something like this every X hours -

1. Automatically shut down the rails application
2. Put up a maintenance page ("Sorry, we'll be back in a few mins")
3. Drop the db, recreate it, and re-migrate it (`rake db:drop; rake db:create; rake db:migrate`)
4. Run my custom rake task that populates the tables again (`rake myApp:update`)
5. Re-start the application

This brings up a few questions

1. How do I have the app restart automatically every X hours? Should I schedule this externally using a cron job? Is there a rails way I can accomplish this?
2. How do I display a maintenance page if the app is down? Again, is this also an external re-direct I need to manage?
3. Most importantly, is there a good way to drop the tables and recreate them or should I be using `rake` tasks? Is there a way to call `rake` tasks at startups? I guess I could create a `.rb` process under `config/initalizers` that would run at startup (but only when `Rails.env == 'production'`)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: this ans might help as well.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193387/restart-rails-server-automatically-after-every-change-in-controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just create a Cron task that runs periodically. That Cron task starts a shell stript that just does all the step you would run manually.
2. There is a gem (https://github.com/biola/turnout) at helps with the maintainance page. It provides rake tasks like `rake maintenance:start` and `rake maintenance:end`.
3. I think it is not necessary to drop the tables. Usually it should be enough to just delete all records and then create new records. If you really have to drop the database, it might be faster to just restore the database schema from a structure dump.

Comment: that's great! Using that gem I could just put up a maintenance page and then run the rake tasks to re-create the DB. I wouldn't even have to bring the app down while the SQLite DB's are being dropped and re-created behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is not a 'rails way' to reload a rails app every so often, since starting and stopping a rails app is *outside* the context of the app itself. A cron job is a fine way to go.
2. Typically a web server is running "in front" of the rails app, apache or nginix are common. The maintenance page would need to be implemented on that level (since the rails app is down for a moment remember), something like a temporary change to the configs and a reload should suffice. Then when bringing that app back online, restore the config to point to the rails app and reload again.
3. Using the rake tasks you have is fine, set the environment variable `RAILS_ENV=production` so they hit the right sqlitedb file. Don't bother attempting to call the rake tasks at rails start up, call them from the script called by your cron job, and then start the app after that.

Comment: Thanks! I would've for sure thought there's a standard way to reload an application, but your explanation for it being outside the scope of the rails stack makes sense. Another user in this thread pointed to a gem that provides a maintenance page as well.

Comment: If you don't plan on shutting down the rails app that gem should do nicely.